# How to use react-router to make sure it works in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Here is my Sandbox code https://codesandbox.io/s/wispy-glitter-spgch?file=/src
what i am trying to do is on click of LOGIN Button trying to rendering the Dashboard page the url does go to the path '/dashboard'but do not render anything
I am not able to find the error
I have done routing in a component and passed that component inside of Context API

On page refresh i.e. in '/dashboard' dashboard section it again goes to login part how to maintain this with state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `exact` parameter in protected route like this:

```
<ProtectedRoute
        path="/dashboard"
        exact
        auth={authState.isAuthenticated}
        component={Dashboard}
/>
```

Comment: @Akhi21 I Forked and Its Working https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-einstein-83unj

Comment: hi @alishi973 There is still one issue on page refresh it again goes to login page

Comment: @Akhi21 its Not React Problem,When You Refreshing Your Page, All State Reset to inital Value and Your `auth` variable reset to false, and you redirecting to Login page
You Must Persist `auth` With token or somthing like this.

Comment: in my real project i do maintain auth token too in localstorage but still on page refresh it it land to login part

Comment: @Akhi21 `token` must persist when ever user `Logged In`.
and retrieve this item from persist storage (like `LocalStorage`) when ever render for first time an and when user have token in ls , its prove user is logged in before (even when token is not valid ) so make request to server,
after first request ,server check's token that sent by user ,if token is not valid (server return `401 unauthorized` ) user redirect to `Login` or else response serve by element.

Comment: hi @alishi973 ok got it, but i am still facing problem to persist the token storage if you got a time please share the code on codesandbox it will be very helpful for me i have made this changes in AuthProve.js file and updated codesanbox https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-yalow-e4kts?file=/App.js

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212653/discussion-between-alishi973-and-akhi21).